# Method that will read different settings in the object and depending on the incoming data execute different methods

Tags: javascript, class

I study vanila JS, and try to optimize my code.
I want to create a universal method that will read different settings and, depending on the incoming data launch another methods.
I don’t really want to use with a lot of **IF IF ELSE**

**What I got**

```
Settings = {
SlideToShow: 2,
SlidetoScrolle: 2,
Scrollable: false
}
```

**My "universal" method**

```
_settingsReader(settings) {
        for (const key in settings) {
            if (Object.hasOwnProperty.call(settings, key)) {
                this._set + key + (settings[key])  
}
```

All problems hide here "this._set + key + (settings[key])". It doesn't call a method.

I just don't understand if something like this is possible. And how to implement it.

**Metods that I want to launch**

```
_setSlideToShow(param);
_setSlidetoScrolle(param);
_setScrollable(param);
```

I hope I was able to explain what I would like to see in the final result.
I will be very happy if someone can help me with this problem.

Comment: `this._set + key + (settings[key])` -> `this["_set" + key](settings[key])`

Comment: Thank you. It work well!